# Distributing data socket among kafka cluster nodes

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, flink-streaming, kafka-producer-api

I want to get data from socket and put it to kafka topic that my flink program can read data from topic and process it. I can do that on one node. But I want to have a kafka cluster with at least three different nodes(different IP address) and poll data from socket to distribute it among nodes.I do not know how to do this and change this code. My simple program is in following:

```
public class WordCount {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    kafka_test objKafka=new kafka_test();
  // Checking input parameters
    final ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
    int myport = 9999;
    String hostname = "localhost";
 // set up the execution environment
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
  StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();


 // make parameters available in the web interface
    env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(params);

    DataStream<String> stream = env.socketTextStream(hostname,myport);

    stream.addSink(objKafka.createStringProducer("testFlink", 
    "localhost:9092"));

    DataStream<String> text = 
    env.addSource(objKafka.createStringConsumerForTopic("testFlink", 
    "localhost:9092", "test"));
    DataStream<Tuple2<String, Long>> counts = text
     .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Long>>() {
                @Override
public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple2<String, Long>> out) 
   {
          // normalize and split the line
             String[] words = value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");

                    // emit the pairs
             for (String word : words) {
                  if (!word.isEmpty()) {
                     out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Long>(word, 1L));
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .keyBy(0)
            .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
            .sum(1);
          // emit result
        if (params.has("output")) {
           counts.writeAsText(params.get("output"));
          } else {
          System.out.println("Printing result to stdout. Use --output 
          to specify output path.");
          counts.print();
         }
    // execute program
    env.execute("Streaming WordCount");

    }//main
   }

  public class kafka_test {
  public FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> createStringConsumerForTopic(
        String topic, String kafkaAddress, String kafkaGroup) {
  //        ************************** KAFKA Properties ******        
     Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaAddress);
    props.setProperty("group.id", kafkaGroup);
    FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> myconsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(
            topic, new SimpleStringSchema(), props);
    myconsumer.setStartFromLatest();     

    return myconsumer;
  }

  public FlinkKafkaProducer<String> createStringProducer(
        String topic, String kafkaAddress) {

        return new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(kafkaAddress,
            topic, new SimpleStringSchema());
     }
  }
```

Would you please guide me how to broadcast a socket stream data between different kafka nodes?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is correct. Kafka will take care of the "distribution" of the data. How data will be distributed among Kafka brokers will depend on the topic configuration.

Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024514/understanding-kafka-topics-and-partitions) to better understand Kafka topics and partitions.

Lets say you have 3 Kafka brokers. Then if you create your topic with 3 replicas and 3 partitions

```
> bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3 --topic my-topic
```

This will cause that your topic will have 3 partitions and each partition will be stored 3 times in your cluster. With 3 brokers you will get stored 1 partition and 2 replicas on each broker.

Then you just have to create your Kafka Sink

```
FlinkKafkaProducer011<String> myProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer011<String>(
        "broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092",
        "my-topic",
        new SimpleStringSchema());

stream.addSink(myProducer);
```

Comment: Dear @belbo thanks for your answer. But suppose I have three brokers with different IP address. So, how data distributed among brokers? Would you please tell me if I have to use your code (which is above) in all brokers?

Comment: Not in the broker. You have two clusters. Kafka cluster - this will consist of multiple brokers, each with different IP. Then Flink cluster - consisting of multiple nodes/servers with different IPs. Code I pasted above is for your Flink job wich will run on Flink cluster. This job will create Kafka producer with IPs of Kafka brokers (`broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092`) and will distribute the data among these Kafka brokers.

Comment: Dear @belbo, Sorry to bother you. In fact, I pump my data from a CSV file to the socket 9999 with this command "cat file.csv | nc -lk 9999". If I send data to the port 9999 of all brokers IP, it is possible that each broker get the same data. how can I distribute all data to three broker? Would you please tell me if Flink master node does that for me? thanks a gain.

Comment: You want to distribute data among Flink nodes, not Kafka brokers. I'm bit confused, because `nc -lk` means you will listening for data, not sending it. Anyway to achieve what you need I guess, you'd need to put some kind of load balancer between netcat and Flink nodes which will take care of distributing data among Flink instances or write a shell script to take care of sending different lines of file to different Flink nodes. But for the production use I'd suggest to use something more robust - maybe Apache NiFi or something.

Comment: Now with "nc -lk", I send data to one port and then read the data from the socket without any problem(on one node). As you just said "I want to distribute data among Flink nodes" but I want to use Kafka to distribute data automatically. But I don't know how to distribute data(which I receive from the socket) among Kafka nodes. I really appreciate it if you guide me.

Comment: You don't have to do anything to distribute data among Kafka brokers. Kafka producer, which is part of your Flink job will take care of it. And how data will be  distributed depends on the number of partitions of the topic you will be writing to.

Comment: Dear @belo, Thank you very much for your perfect guidance. If Flink job will take care of distributing data between kafka brokers via kafka producer, I suppose I do not need to use NiFi to balance data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186105/discussion-between-m-gh-and-belo).