# Error: Replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0, when I create a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have one problem in running Kafka in the cluster. I explain it one by one.
First, When I run Kafka commands on the cluster CSSH from my computer, I get this error:

> Error while executing topic command : Replication factor: 2 larger than available brokers: 1. [2019-01-06 15:12:36,587] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 2 larger than available brokers: 1.
>   (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)

In fact, I run CSSH on my computer to access to the cluster, after running Zookeeper and Kafka server on the cluster, when I run command of creating a topic I get the error.
In the cluster, I have these setting on the server.properties on node1:

```
broker.id=1
port=9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://150.20.11.137:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
sockeet.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=10073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect= 150.20.11.134:2186, 150.20.11.137:2186, 
150.20.11.157:2186
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

In zookeeper.properties of each node I have this setting:

```
 dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
 clientPort=2186
 maxClientCnxns=0
```

Also, I run each command on the cluster nodes to run Kafka and Zookeeper:

```
./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh ./config/zookeeper.properties
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh ./config/server.properties
```

After that, I want to create a topic with this command in the cluster and then I get above error on each node:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2186 -- 
 replication-factor 2 --partitions 3 --topic testFlink
```

Would you please tell what the problem is exactly? And what is wrong in my cluster setting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any error in kafka broker log, during start?

Comment: Dear @wardziniak thank you for your feedback. If you mean result of this command "./bin/kafka-server-start.sh ./config/server.properties", There is no error in that.

Comment: I think it is related to cluster properties. Would you please tell me what the right cluster setup is?thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that you've been able to form a cluster successfully. While booting up the cluster, please ensure you're starting all the 3 zookeeper nodes first, and then the three brokers. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032314/how-to-ensure-a-kafka-cluster-is-fully-up/54032716#54032716) post, to check if Kafka has formed a cluster.

**Update:**
I had overlooked the zookeeper properties you're using, which is missing the essential key-value pairs, required for creating a cluster. The following properties for zookeeper should be good to start with. Considering you have 3 zookeeper nodes, the `zookeeper.properties` or `zoo.cfg` (if it's a standalone zk) file on the zk nodes should look something like the following.

## zk-1 properties

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
clientPort=2186
dataDir=/opt/zookeeper/data
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=<zk_2-ip>:2888:3888
server.3=<zk_3-ip>:2888:3888
```

## zk-2 properties

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
clientPort=2186
dataDir=/opt/zookeeper/data
server.1=<zk_1-ip>:2888:3888
server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.3=<zk_3-ip>:2888:3888
```

## zk-3 properties

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
clientPort=2186
dataDir=/opt/zookeeper/data
server.1=<zk_1-ip>:2888:3888
server.2=<zk_2-ip>:2888:3888
server.3=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
```

Okay, so before you start the zookeeper processes, you need to do one more thing. Checkout the `dataDir` property that you're using, in this example it's `/opt/zookeeper/data`. For each of the zookeepers, you've to create a file called `myid` and enter the value of 1 for zk-1, 2 for zk-2 and 3 for zk-3. Then you start the zookeepers, and it should form a cluster. You can use a bash cmd like `echo "1" > /opt/zookeeper/data/myid` for zk-1. Rest will be similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, I first run three zookeeper nodes first and then three brokers without any problems;but I have a problem to create a topic. I can make a topic on one broker. Would you please suggest me the best source to setup a cluster on different nodes physically?Thanks.

Comment: @M_Gh You can checkout the Confluent Ansible playbooks, and my fork that shows how to do it in VMs using Vagrant. In a few commands, you can get a cluster running locally. https://github.com/cricket007/cp-ansible/tree/addVagrant/vagrant

Comment: Dear @cicket_007 thanks but I have to set my cluster on different node physically.

Comment: Dear @Bitswazsky thank you very much for your complete answer, I will set up my cluster again and write the result here. Also,I think that I have a problem in set up of "server.properties" file for brokers.

Comment: Dear @Bitswazsky I set up "zookeeper.properties" according to your guidance and topic was built without any errors. But I cannot run producer and consumer command. `./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic testFlink --from-beginning` I got this error **[2019-01-07 09:17:16,861] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-36276] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)**.

Comment: Your broker is exposed though the ip, so localhost is not supposed to work. If you are submitting through broker-1, try using this cmd: `./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 150.20.11.137:9092 --topic testFlink --from-beginning`

Comment: Dear @Bitswazsky thanks a lot. It solve the issue. Would you please tell me if I want to have a special topic for each node I have to use IP address of that node while I am creating a topic on the node?

Comment: In a cluster, there's nothing like `special topic for each node`. If you have multiple partitions in a topic, those would be distributed across brokers. A topic is not tied to any particular broker.

Comment: Dear @Bitswazsky thank you for your complete guidance. Therefore, I do not need to use IP address of nodes while I am creating a topic on that node. Thanks a lot.

Comment: While you're creating a topic it takes the zookeeper host-port as an argument. Zookeepers talk to each other in the cluster internally, so, while querying for any topic metadata, you don't need to specify the same zookeeper host:port that you used for creating the topic.You can refer to the Kafka documentation for the same: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186310/discussion-between-bitswazsky-and-m-gh).

Answer (score 2):

The only reason this error could occur is if your brokers are not connected to zookeeper cluster.
How are you running your Kafka broker? Are you running it as a service or a daemon process? Can you share logs?

You can check if a broker is running simply by running the command

> nc -vz 150.20.11.137 9092

This would fail if the broker is not running.

I would suggest you use a zookeeper WEB UI like Zookeeper Navigator. Running it on docker is the easiest way. Here's the [docker compose file](https://gist.github.com/elkozmon/85a3eaee0f0cc2c613c932f0d7745180) for it. This will help you identify if there's any problem with zookeeper and all brokers are indeed connected to it.

I would also suggest you use yahoo Kafka manager. Its a web UI for your cluster and the most elegant way to manage your cluster. Here's [docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/sheepkiller/kafka-manager/) for it.

And yes, Your zookeeper properties need to include the server IPs of all other zookeeper nodes like explained by Bitswazsky.

Comment: Dear @Ankur rana thank you for your attention. I run my Kafka broker as a service now. For first time I ran it as a daemon process even though I have this error in both of them.

Comment: If you are still facing the problem, Can you share kafka logs?

Comment: Dear @Ankur rana I set the zookeeper cluster without any problem but I cannot run consumer and producer that I think it is related to Kafka cluster.

Comment: How do you know that your cluster is actually set?

Comment: Zookeeper server is run without any problem. Also, Kafka server is. But I do not know if there is any problem on Kafka or Zookeeper server. Do I have to set up **producer.properties** and **consumer.properties** too?

Comment: yes... ofcource, you'll have to atleast set bootstrap.servers properties.
How are you producing messages in the cluster?

Comment: I have to receive my data from socket so I send my data from file to the socket via `cat file.csv | nc -lk myport`. Now I have to distribute this data to the Kafka cluster equally. Therefore, I want to use **Apache Nifi**, however I have never worked with **Nifi** at all and I have  no idea what problems I face with.

Comment: Dear @Ankur rana, I posted my code that I use now in this link. Please see that: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/54006023/6640504]

Comment: this seems correct. 
Have you tried producing data using kafka-console-producer.sh?

Comment: If you mean that I run producer with **kafka-console-producer.sh** and then write line by line data to it, I did that. But I have a stream of data and this way does not help me.

Comment: I dont understand... Are you still facing the original problem?

Comment: No, I setup Zookeeper again according to @Bitswazsky explanation  and Kafka cluster works just fine.