# Association between Partitions w.r.t to broker and Partition with respect to topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka I'm trying to develop an enterprise level application using Kafka. While going through literature I found some documents describing partition, replication factor with respect to each broker. While trying to create a topic on broker I can vary no. of partition, replication factor for each topic. So my question is how replication factor, partition is associated in Both the context for the whole system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Kafka Topics and Partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024514/understanding-kafka-topics-and-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

> with respect to each broker

Partitions and replications are only set on a **per-topic** basis.

The values that you set in the broker properties are the defaults if topic auto-creation is enabled (which is not recommended)