# Multiple Consumer threads using Alpakka connector

Tags: java, apache-kafka, akka-stream, alpakka

I am using Alpakka kafka connector to consume packets from kafka. I am using Consumer as a CommittableSource. I would like to create multiple consumer threads on a single machine and use them as a single source. How can I achieve that?

Currently, I have created multiple sources using Consumer.CommittableSource and merge all the sources into a single source using "merge" function. But I am not sure whether this is a right approach as I am not creating the threads.

Please find below the Source code that I am currently using :

```
public Source<ConsumerMessage.CommittableMessage<String, String>, Consumer.Control> source() {
Source finalSource = Source.empty();
        for (int index = 0; index < consumerConfig.getNoOfConsumers(); index++) {
            finalSource = finalSource.merge(Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, subscription));
        }
return finalSource;
}
```

Comment: (Without any experience) I thought concurrent processing on a single topic can only be achieved by specifying multiple partitions for that topic. Every partition can have its own consumer (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024514/understanding-kafka-topics-and-partitions)

Comment: @Conffusion : I already know that every partition can have its own consumer. I was asking how to consume multiple packets but by alpakka connector.

Comment: I was just sharing my little theoretical knowledge in the hope it could help. I will not be able to help you further. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you believe you need more threads? More ofen you would want to share a single Kafka consumer client instance across multiple streams.

You should not merge elements from multiple `Consumer.committableSource`s into one stream, it will not work with batched committing.

Would running the same stream setup multiple times solve your need?

Comment: If I do not require the batch committing, would merging elements from multiple `committableSource` into one stream provide the same performance as provided by `Consumer.committablePartitionedSource` ?
`committablePartitionedSource` would create source per partition and thus it provide batch committting ?

Comment: No, `committablePartitionedSource` uses a single Kafka consumer internally. Committing works with it.