# Does same partition really never be consumed by more than one consumers on a single group at the same time

Tags: apache-kafka

Assume a topic has 2 partitions.
We have 2 consumers in a same group both consume from that topic: Consumer A consumes **partition 0**, Consumer B consumes **partition 1**.
Consumer A is the group leader of the consumer group.

At a moment, Consumer B got a batch of messages from the topic, for example message: X, Y. Right after that, Consumer B stopped.

After a while, Consumer A thinks that Consumer B is dead, and decides to rebalance and consume from **partition 1**. It gets messages: X, Y, Z (in order) and then writes to a database.

After that, Consumer B resumes the execution, had no idea that some time has passed, and continue to write message X, Y, overwriting the effect of Z.
And then Consumer B fails completely.

Is it possible? If yes, the simple way of consuming messages and upserting to a database might not be safe.

Comment: There's a very good explanation.. hope this will help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51829144/7098046

Comment: Your description seems to be missing when/if the consumer committed any offsets. And if B dies, then the group rebalances, then A would read both partitions

Comment: It doesn't matter offset is commited or not by A here. Because B doesn't read anything from committed offsets topic when it writes to Database.

Comment: Kafka Consumers always query the offsets topic. You cannot disable that

Comment: Kafka Consumers as I remember only querying the committed offset topic at the start. You dont know about raft/paxos consensus or distributed locking, do you?

Comment: Kafka currently uses ZAB, so no

Comment: So you know how Zab work#??

Answer (score 0):

> Consumer A thinks that Consumer B has dead, decide to rebalance and consume from partition 1. It got messages: X, Y, Z (in order) and then write to a database

Okay, let's say it *commits offsets* for each of those messages as well.

If B starts back up, it will start to read offsets **after** the most recent committed value, and not re-read data that it had tried to before unless the consumer was manually seeked to that position.

Comment: It's stopped right after receving messages, but before write to Database, so it didnt touch committed offsets topic to determine offsets is old version or not.

Comment: B doesnt fail, it's just paused, because of GC pause, VM pause or someone accidentally send stop signal to B.

Comment: Failure or pausing would still cause a rebalance and loss of processed record state

Comment: B can detect it has read old offsets but ONLY after B has already written to the database. Above problem still there

Comment: Pause of B can cause A to rebalance, but B didnt even know right away that itself has already left the group when it performing the write

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Ideally, you wouldn't write a database client in a consumer on your own, anyway, and would rather use Kafka Connect framework, which has fault tolerance controls