# Receive the message by all Consumer in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm new to Kafka and I'm trying to exchange messages between several systems (two systems at the moment) using Kafka.

Currently, I have managed to send messages from multiple Producers to a Consumer.

But I want messages from any Producer to be sent to all Consumer.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
     - "2181:2181"
    networks:
     - my_network
    restart: unless-stopped

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
     - "9092:9092"
    expose:
     - "9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.11.30
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "topic:5:5"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: 1
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: 4073741824
      KAFKA_LOG_SEGMENT_BYTES: 1073741824
      KAFKA_RETENTION_CHECK_INTERVAL_MS: 300000
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
     - my_network
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

producer.py

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaProducer

kafka_server = "192.168.11.30:9092"

topic = "topic"

producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers=[kafka_server],
    value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode("utf-8"),
    acks='all',
)

while True:
    data = input()
    producer.send(topic, value=data)
    producer.flush()
```

consumer.py

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

kafka_server = "192.168.11.30:9092"

topic = "topic"

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    bootstrap_servers=[kafka_server],
    value_deserializer=json.loads,
    enable_auto_commit=False,
    auto_offset_reset="latest",
    group_id="my-group",
)

consumer.subscribe([topic])

try:
    for data in consumer:
        print(data.value)
        consumer.commit()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    consumer.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Kafka Topics and Partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024514/understanding-kafka-topics-and-partitions)

Comment: Read about **consumer groups**.